# How do I determine if a PHP script I'm running is as a result of mod_rewrite pointing to it?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP script and I'd like to know if it's been executed as a result of mod_rewrite redirecting the request to it.

Is there anything I can easily inspect simply to get a yes or no answer?  Is there any way to get the rewritten path rather than the one that was originally requested?

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something "wrong". Why does this matter to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a `print_r($_SERVER);` and you'll be able to figure out what you need. On my Apache server:

- Requests redirected through mod_rewrite have a `REDIRECT_URL` parameter
- Both `REDIRECT_URL` and `REQUEST_URI` point to the originally requested URL
- Both `SCRIPT_NAME` and `PHP_SELF` point to the actual PHP script